# Find first occurrence of any number of a vector

Tags: matlab, vector, find

I want to find the first occurrence of either 2,3 or 5 in x. The output should be 7 as 3 appears first at index 7. How do I do that?

```
x = [0 0 0 0 1 1 3 5 2 0 0];
y = [2 3 5]; 

output = 7
```

I can use find(x == 3, 1) to find just one number but how do I do that for multiple numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLABs `find` is already the right choice in combination with `ismember`

In this case

```
>> find(ismember(x,y),1)
```

will do what you want. It returns the index of the first occurence of array `y` in array `x`. This will work for any lengths `y` might have.

Answer (score 1):

Find() accepts a logical term as an argument, so you can use your call but instead of checking only for 3, use something like:
(x==2 || x==3 || x==5)

I'm general, you might want to use the intersect() function.

Comment: This solution only works for specific arrays `y` (in this case `y = [2,3,4]`). Imagine `lenght(y)` would be 100, you would have to write an logical expression consisting of 100 `or` connected terms.